# How to make a child element fill his parent element

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Here is an excerpt of my xaml view. The textBlock text could be quite long. However I would like to make the line in column 0 (LineGeometry) to fit the same height as this TextBlock.

```
  <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="40"></ColumnDefinition>
      <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Path Grid.Column="0" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="3" Fill="Black">
      <Path.Data>
        <GeometryGroup>
            <LineGeometry StartPoint="7,0" EndPoint="7,70"/>
            <EllipseGeometry Center="7,20" RadiusX="5" RadiusY="5" />
        </GeometryGroup>
      </Path.Data>
    </Path>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"  Text="ldkfjlgdlgjljd &#x0a; fsm &#x0a; jklgf &#x0a;dmj &#x0a;dfm &#x0a;ljdgms &#x0a; kjlk &#x0a; jfdlkjsg"></TextBlock>
  </Grid>
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Have you tried to remove Canvas element and place Border in the Grid directly?

Comment: And possibly making the `TextBlock` a child of the `Border`?

Comment: I removed the Border , It was only use for debugging purpose

Comment: @OlehNechytailo: Removing the Canvas does not change anything unfortunately

Answer (score 2):

This meets somewhat your requirement

```
<Grid>
    <Canvas>
        <Border BorderBrush="#FFFF00" BorderThickness="2">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Grid Margin="5,0">
                    <Border Width="2" Background="Black"  />
                    <Ellipse Fill="Black"  Width="12" Height="12" />
                </Grid>
                <TextBlock  Text="ldkfjlgdlgjljd &#x0a; fsm &#x0a; jklgf &#x0a;dmj &#x0a;dfm &#x0a;ljdgms &#x0a; kjlk &#x0a; jfdlkjsg&#x0a; jfdlkjsg"></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks Sayka, It does the job!

Answer (score 1):

Heres a rough working example. I would suggest adding null checking etc
Firstly lets create a converter that returns a `Point`

```
public class LineLengthConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {            
        var textBox = value as TextBlock;

        double textHeight = textBox.ActualHeight;
        var endpoint = new Point(7.0, textHeight);
        return endpoint;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Now the the Xaml (Ive added all the xaml so that you can see reference to the converter as a resource. 
NB the `TextBlock` is in a `Canvas` Panel
and the Binding of `LineGeometry.EndPoint`

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication9.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication9">
<Window.Resources>
    <local:LineLengthConverter x:Key="LineLengthConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="40"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid>
        <Border BorderBrush="#FFFF00" BorderThickness="2">                
                <Path Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="3" Fill="Black">
                    <Path.Data>
                        <GeometryGroup>
                            <LineGeometry StartPoint="7,0" EndPoint="{Binding ElementName=someText, Converter={StaticResource LineLengthConverter}}" />
                            <EllipseGeometry Center="7,20" RadiusX="5" RadiusY="5" />
                        </GeometryGroup>
                    </Path.Data>
                </Path>                
        </Border>
        <Canvas>
            <TextBlock x:Name="someText"  Text="ldkfjlgdlgjljd &#x0a; fsm &#x0a; jklgf &#x0a;dmj &#x0a;dfm &#x0a;ljdgms&#x0a; jklgf &#x0a;dmj &#x0a;dfm &#x0a;ljdgms &#x0a; kjlk &#x0a; jfdlkjsg"></TextBlock>
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>        
</Grid>
```

Hope it helps